# Can't extend controller in fuel php

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'm tring to create a basecontroller which includes auth-check and extend it in other controllers.However,it displays not found error.

This is the basecontoller in fuel/app/classes/controller. Filename is admin.php.

```
class Controller_Admin extends Controller
{
    public function before(){

    }
}
```

This is a sample controller in fuel/app/classes/controller.

```
class Controller_Sample extends Admin
{

}
```

This codes cause this error.

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]:
Class 'Admin' not found
```

How should I solve this?

Comment: There isnt class admin, im seeing class Controller_admin instead???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Admin` use `Controller_Admin`

```
class Controller_Sample extends Controller_Admin
{

}
```